# docker vagrant ubuntu 16.04 - No usable default provider could be found for your system

Tags: ubuntu, docker, vagrant

I am trying to follow from a book on Scrapy. The author uses a testing environment built with vagrant and docker. The environment is required to follow the tutorials in the book. I don't know anything about either of these technologies, but have been struggling since yesterday to get everything running. After hours of searching, and trying various things (such as pulling my finger nails out,) I have made absolutely no progress.

I've attempted to include any, and all information that might be relevant. Sorry for the poor formatting for some of the data. I am new here. Also I had to remove 'http' from some of the code embedded links, because stackoverflow won't let me post too many hyperlinks.

the version numbers are: vagrant 1.8.5, docker 1.12.1, ubuntu 16.04

When I go into the directory that contains the vagrant file and run 'vagrant up --no-parallel' I get the infamous "No usable default provider could be found for your system", error.

'vagrant box list' returns 'There are no installed boxes! Use `vagrant box add` to add some.'

'vagrant global-status' returns "There are no active Vagrant environments on this computer! Or, you haven't destroyed and recreated Vagrant environments that were started with an older version of Vagrant." (my OS is a completely fresh install)

"docker info" returns:

```
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 1.12.1
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 0
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: overlay bridge host null
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: apparmor seccomp
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-31-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 3.823 GiB
Name: chris-Inspiron-1440
ID: SIHD:H76B:TWRL:FZSA:MKGE:O4WK:IAZS:LQIS:SQ76:YFTY:7AD4:KJ5T
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: //index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8

systemctl status docker.service returns:

● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2016-09-03 16:05:43 EDT; 48min ago
     Docs: //docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 2659 (dockerd)
    Tasks: 17
   Memory: 55.6M
      CPU: 1.995s
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           ├─2659 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://
           └─2713 docker-containerd -l unix:///var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.so
```

sudo docker Daemon -D returns:

```
FATA[0000] Error starting daemon: pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/run/docker.pid
```

The vagrant file that comes with the book:

```
ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = "docker"

host_vagrantfile = "./Vagrantfile.dockerhost"
force_host_vm = TRUE

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    # -------------- Web server --------------

    config.vm.define "web" do |web|

        web.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
            d.image = "scrapybook/web"
            #d.build_dir = "../scrapybook-docker-web"
            d.name = "web"

            d.vagrant_machine = "docker-provider"
            d.vagrant_vagrantfile = host_vagrantfile
            d.force_host_vm = force_host_vm
        end

        web.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true

        web.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9312, host: 9312
        web.vm.hostname = "web"
    end

    # -------------- Spark server --------------

    config.vm.define "spark" do |spark|

        spark.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
            d.image = "scrapybook/spark"
            #d.build_dir = "../scrapybook-docker-spark"
            d.name = "spark"

            d.vagrant_machine = "docker-provider"
            d.vagrant_vagrantfile = host_vagrantfile
            d.force_host_vm = force_host_vm
        end

        spark.vm.synced_folder ".", "/root/book"

        spark.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 21, host: 21
        (30000..30009).each do |port|
            spark.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: port, host: port
        end
        spark.vm.hostname = "spark"
    end


    # -------------- ES server --------------

    config.vm.define "es" do |es|

        es.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
            d.image = "scrapybook/es"
            #d.build_dir = "../scrapybook-docker-es"
            d.name = "es"

            d.vagrant_machine = "docker-provider"
            d.vagrant_vagrantfile = host_vagrantfile
            d.force_host_vm = force_host_vm
        end

        es.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true

        es.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9200, host: 9200
        es.vm.hostname = "es"
    end


    # -------------- Redis server --------------

    config.vm.define "redis" do |redis|

        redis.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
            d.image = "scrapybook/redis"
            #d.build_dir = "../scrapybook-docker-redis"
            d.name = "redis"

            d.vagrant_machine = "docker-provider"
            d.vagrant_vagrantfile = host_vagrantfile
            d.force_host_vm = force_host_vm
        end

        redis.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true

        redis.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 6379, host: 6379
        redis.vm.hostname = "redis"
    end


    # -------------- MySQL server --------------

    config.vm.define "mysql" do |mysql|

        mysql.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
            d.image = "scrapybook/mysql"
            #d.build_dir = "../scrapybook-docker-mysql"
            d.name = "mysql"

            d.vagrant_machine = "docker-provider"
            d.vagrant_vagrantfile = host_vagrantfile
            d.force_host_vm = force_host_vm
        end

        mysql.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true

        mysql.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3306
        mysql.vm.hostname = "mysql"
    end
    # -------------- 3 Scrapyd servers --------------

    {
        "scrapyd1" => 6801,
        "scrapyd2" => 6802, 
        "scrapyd3" => 6803,
    }.each do |host, port|

        config.vm.define host do |scp|

            scp.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
                d.image = "scrapybook/dev"
                #d.build_dir = "../scrapybook-docker-dev"
                d.name = host

                d.link("spark:spark")
                d.link("web:web")

                d.vagrant_machine = "docker-provider"
                d.vagrant_vagrantfile = host_vagrantfile
                d.force_host_vm = force_host_vm
            end

            scp.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true

            scp.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 6800, host: port
            scp.vm.hostname = host
        end
    end

    # -------------- Dev machine --------------

    config.vm.define "dev", primary: true do |dev|

        dev.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
            d.image = "scrapybook/dev"
            #d.build_dir = "../scrapybook-docker-dev"
            d.name = "dev"

            d.link("web:web")
            d.link("spark:spark")
            d.link("scrapyd1:scrapyd1")
            d.link("scrapyd2:scrapyd2")
            d.link("scrapyd3:scrapyd3")
            d.link("mysql:mysql")
            d.link("redis:redis")
            d.link("es:es")

            d.vagrant_machine = "docker-provider"
            d.vagrant_vagrantfile = host_vagrantfile
            d.force_host_vm = force_host_vm
        end

        dev.vm.synced_folder ".", "/root/book"

        dev.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 6800, host: 6800
        dev.vm.hostname = "dev"
    end

    config.ssh.username = 'root'
    config.ssh.private_key_path = 'insecure_key'
end
```

There is also a file named Vagrant.dockerhost, which is referred to from within the Vagrantfile:

```
# Set if you are behind proxy
#proxy_url = "http://user:pass@proxy.com:8080/"

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    if !defined?(proxy_url) || proxy_url.nil? || proxy_url.empty?

        # No proxy setup necessary.

    else
        # Setup proxies

        ENV['http_proxy']  = proxy_url
        ENV['https_proxy'] = proxy_url
    end

    config.vm.define "docker-provider"
    config.vm.box = "lookfwd/scrapybook"

    # Setting up ports
    (
        [9200] +                      # ES
        [6379] +                      # Redis
        [3306] +                      # MySQL
        [9312] +                      # Web
        (6800..6803).to_a +           # Scrapyd
        [21] + (30000..30009).to_a  + # Spark
    []).each do |port|
        config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: port, host: port
    end

    # Set the mem/cpu requirements
    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
        vb.memory = 2048
        vb.cpus = 4
        vb.name = "docker-provider"
        vb.check_guest_additions = false
    end
end
```

Comment: Hi Chris - Have you installed VirtualBox on your host OS?

Answer (score 0):

the solution to this is to install VirtualBox

Comment: Hi Chris Hamberg, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your answer is very brief, and not as useful as it could be; with some context it would make a better answer. For example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.

Comment: I asked the question. The details were already included in the question.

Comment: Ah, sorry - I saw the answer come up in the review queue, and hadn't realised you were also the questioner :(-

Answer (score 0):

if you only need to use docker without VM Host, change force_host_vm = TRUE to FALSE (force_host_vm = FALSE)